# SAS:add one column from tableB to tableA

Tags: sas

I have two table looks like and I want to add column score to tableA from tableB, then get tableC, how to do in SAS?

the only rule is to add a column in tableA name "score " and its value is same as column "score" in tableB (which are all the same in tableB)

```
+----+---+---+---+
| id | b | c | d |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
|  2 | 6 | 8 | 3 |
|  3 | 7 | 8 | 1 |
|  4 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
|  5 | 6 | 8 | 3 |
|  6 | 7 | 8 | 1 |
+----+---+---+---+
       tableA

+---+---+-------+
| e | f | score |
+---+---+-------+
| 3 | 7 |    11 |
| 4 | 6 |    11 |
| 5 | 5 |    11 |
+---+---+-------+
      tableB

+----+---+---+---+-------+
| id | b | c | d | score |
+----+---+---+---+-------+
|  1 | 5 | 7 | 2 |    11 |
|  2 | 6 | 8 | 3 |    11 |
|  3 | 7 | 8 | 1 |    11 |
|  4 | 5 | 7 | 2 |    11 |
|  5 | 6 | 8 | 3 |    11 |
|  6 | 7 | 8 | 1 |    11 |
+----+---+---+---+-------+
       tableC
```

Comment: Can you provide Table C to explain how the result is expected to look?

Comment: @RegiMathew please check

Comment: How do you want to expand the three rows of SCORE in tableB to fill the six rows in tableC?  Is the last value carried forward?  Do you loop through the values repeating the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If the "**id**" is present in both tables, you can use the following to create Table C:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE tableC AS
SELECT a.*, b.score
FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b
ON a.id = b.id;
QUIT;
```

Please confirm that this is what you need?

Comment: Where does the score come from?

Comment: If table B has scores 1,2,3, would table C have the scores 1,2,3,1,2,3 ?

Comment: @Richard it will only be one clomun of score

Comment: Understood. Suppose Table A has six rows and you want to add score column from Table B that has three rows.  How do you distribute the three score values in Table B over the six rows of Table A?